# Pandas selecting the values from Multilevel columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a below small tested pandas code, where i have an excl file called `Firmware_sheet.xlsx` where we have multiple details which i see divided into multilevel columns, So from there i need to extract some information.

I am just learning how to work in multilevel Columns, i tried but not able to get it for now..

### Pandas code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
firmware = pd.ExcelFile("Firmware_sheet.xlsx")
df = firmware.parse("Sheet1")
print(df)
```

### DataFrame output:

```
$ ./Firmware_pandas.py
       Applicance Name                Appliance FQDN  Location  Applicance Model  Appliance Details                          BTfra Details                  Unnamed: 6         Unnamed: 7                          Unnamed: 8                  Unnamed: 9        Unnamed: 10                                    Unnamed: 11                 Unnamed: 12        Unnamed: 13
0              NaN                           NaN       NaN               NaN           Composer  Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module                         NaN                NaN  Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module                         NaN                NaN  Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy                         NaN                NaN
1              NaN                           NaN       NaN               NaN    Firmware Verion                       Firmware Version  Compatible with Composer ?  Supported Version                     Firmware Verion  Compatible with Composer ?  Supported Version                                Firmware Verion  Compatible with Composer ?  Supported Version
2           ov0001  ov0001.pti.TN-cpq01.test.com  TN-CPQ01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                    NA#                         NA#                NA#                             1.2.4.0                          No           1.5.11.0                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
3           ov0002  ov0002.pti.mx-gdl01.test.com  MX-GDL01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                    NA#                         NA#                NA#                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
4           ov0004  ov0004.pti.AM-aAM01.test.com  AM-AAM01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
5           ov1001  ov1001.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
6           ov1002  ov1002.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.08                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.2.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
7           ov2001  ov2001.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
8           ov2002  ov2002.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
9           ov2003  ov2003.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.3.1002                          No         1.4.1.1003
10          ov2004  ov2004.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.3.1002                          No         1.4.1.1003
11          ov2005  ov2005.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
12          ov2006  ov2006.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC02  Synergy Composer   4.20.02-0395878                                    1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
13          ov2007  ov2007.pti.AM-PTC01.test.com  AM-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
14          ov3001  ov3001.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
15          ov3002  ov3002.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
16          ov3003  ov3003.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
17          ov3004  ov3004.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
18          ov3005  ov3005.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
19          ov3006  ov3006.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer   5.00.01-0410269                                    1.18                         NA#                NA#                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         NaN                NA#
20          ov3007  ov3007.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer   5.00.01-0410269                                    1.18                         NA#                NA#                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         NaN                NA#
21          ov3008  ov3008.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer   5.00.01-0410269                                    1.18                         NA#                NA#                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         NaN                NA#
22          ov4001  ov4001.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
23          ov4002  ov4002.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
24          ov4003  ov4003.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
25          ov4004  ov4004.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
26          ov4005  ov4005.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
27          ov4006  ov4006.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer   5.00.01-0410269                                    1.18                         NA#                NA#                           1.5.105.0                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         NaN                NA#
28          ov4007  ov4007.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer   5.00.01-0410269                                    1.18                         NA#                NA#                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         NaN                NA#
29          ov4008  ov4008.pti.HL-PTC01.test.com  HL-PTC01  Synergy Composer   5.00.01-0410269                                    1.18                         NA#                NA#                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         NaN                NA#
30          ov6001      ov6001.BT-blr01.test.com  BT-BLR01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
31          ov6002      ov6002.BT-blr01.test.com  BT-BLR01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
32          ov6003      ov6003.BT-blr01.test.com  BT-BLR01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.18                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                          No                NA#
33          ov6004      ov6004.BT-blr01.test.com  BT-BLR01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
34          ov6005      ov6005.BT-blr01.test.com  BT-BLR01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
35          ov6006      ov6006.BT-blr01.test.com  BT-BLR01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
36          ov7001      ov7001.cn-sha01.test.com  CN-SHA01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
37          ov8001  ov8001.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
38          ov8002  ov8002.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
39          ov8003  ov8003.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
40          ov8004  ov8004.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
41          ov8005  ov8005.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
42          ov8006  ov8006.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
43          ov8007  ov8007.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
44          ov8008  ov8008.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.16                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.3.0.1005                          No         1.4.1.1003
45          ov8009  ov8009.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
46          OV8010  ov8010.pti.BT-nda02.test.com  BT-NDA02  Synergy Composer    5.00.00-0400525                                   1.18                          No               3.01                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         Yes                NA#
47          ovd001  ovd001.pti.HL-htc01.test.com  HL-HTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                   1.17                          No               2.04                            1.5.11.0                         Yes                NA#                                     1.4.0.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
48          ovd002  ovd002.pti.HL-htc01.test.com  HL-HTC01  Synergy Composer    5.00.01-0410269                                   1.18                          No               3.01                                 NA#                         NA#                NA#                                     1.5.0.1004                         Yes                NA#
49          ovt001   ovt001.cc.HL-htc01.test.com  HL-HTC01  Synergy Composer    4.20.02-0395878                                    NA#                         NA#                NA#                             1.4.6.0                          No           1.5.11.0                                     1.3.1.1003                          No         1.4.1.1003
```

Though i have given the `df` details above but just to give a view to understand how this excl looks like is as follows..

[image]

### Expected output:

```
Applicance Name Composer Firmware Verion    Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module Firmware Version      Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module Firmware     Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy Firmware Verion
4.20.02-0395878                             1.17                                                        1.17                                            1.17
```

Thanks for the any help on this.

Edit:   (df.columns.tolist()) output as Jezrael asked.

```
[('Applicance Name', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2'), ('Appliance FQDN', 'Unnamed: 1_level_1', 'Unnamed: 1_level_2'), ('Location', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1', 'Unnamed: 2_level_2'), ('Applicance Model', 'Unnamed: 3_level_1', 'Unnamed: 3_level_2'), ('Appliance Details', 'Composer', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Firmware Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Supported Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Supported Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Supported Version')]
```

Desired Columns..

```
[('Applicance Name', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2'),('Appliance Details', 'Composer', 'Firmware Verion'),('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Firmware Version'),('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Firmware Verion')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use `header=[0,1,2]` for`MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Firmware_sheet.xlsx", header=[0,1,2], sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Then remove unnamed values and flaten columns:

```
df.columns = [' '.join(y for y in x if 'Unnamed' not in y) for x in df.columns]
```

Last select columns names - first column and all columns with `Firmware Verion` text:

```
df = df.filter(regex='Applicance Name|Firmware Verion')
```

Comment: @kulfi - If working what is `print (firmware.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @kulfi - Added to answer

Comment: but it prints all the columns as an multiIndex but it works.

Comment: @kulfi - If working correct, then super :) Not necessary testing it.

Comment: @kulfi - thank you, and what is expected column names? Not sure if understand your expected output

Comment: Sorry there is long list which i can not put in comment hence will put the desired column in the post itself.

Comment: can you explain `df.columns = [' '.join(y for y in x if 'Unnamed' not in y) for x in df.columns]` please.

Comment: @kulfi - Sure, it means join values together but filter out all columns names with `Unnamed`

Comment: I m just learning this part `y for y in x if 'Unnamed' not in y`, thank you