# Selecting the Sub-columns In MultiIndex DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is Just in continuation to the [Pandas selecting the values from Multilevel columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61007592/pandas-selecting-the-values-from-multilevel-columns#61007621) , where i have multiIndex'd columns and I'm trying to fetch few columns out of it.

### DatFrame :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
df = pd.read_excel("Firmware_sheet.xlsx", header=[0,1,2], sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.columns = [''.join(y for y in x if 'Unnamed' not in y) for x in df.columns]
df = df.filter(regex='Applicance Name|Firmware Verion')
print(df)
```

### Dataframe output:

```
$ ./Firmware_pandas.py
   Applicance Name Appliance DetailsComposerFirmware Verion BTfra DetailsSynergy 12Gb SAS Connection ModuleFirmware Verion BTfra DetailsVirtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for SynergyFirmware Verion
0           ov0001                          4.20.02-0395878                                            1.2.4.0                                                     1.3.1.1003
1           ov0002                          4.20.02-0395878                                                NA#                                                     1.4.0.1003
2           ov0004                          4.20.02-0395878                                                NA#                                                     1.4.0.1003
3           ov1001                          4.20.02-0395878                                                NA#                                                     1.3.0.1005
----------------------------- sniped output ------------------------------------
```

### DataFrame columns:

```
[('Applicance Name', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2'), ('Appliance FQDN', 'Unnamed: 1_level_1', 'Unnamed: 1_level_2'), ('Location', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1', 'Unnamed: 2_level_2'), ('Applicance Model', 'Unnamed: 3_level_1', 'Unnamed: 3_level_2'), ('Appliance Details', 'Composer', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Firmware Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Supported Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Supported Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Supported Version')]
```

### Issue:

It looks like the `df.filter(regex='Applicance Name|Firmware Verion')`  here the `regex` only Picking up one of the column from the MultiIndex column and not picking another one `('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Firmware Version')` and picking only `('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Firmware Verion')`.

I am expecting the `('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Firmware Version')` column to be printed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is there is `verion` and `version`, so is possible simplify solution for select both:

```
a = [('Applicance Name', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2'), ('Appliance FQDN', 'Unnamed: 1_level_1', 'Unnamed: 1_level_2'), ('Location', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1', 'Unnamed: 2_level_2'), ('Applicance Model', 'Unnamed: 3_level_1', 'Unnamed: 3_level_2'), ('Appliance Details', 'Composer', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Firmware Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module', 'Supported Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module', 'Supported Version'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Firmware Verion'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Compatible with Composer ?'), ('BTfra Details', 'Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy', 'Supported Version')]

#sample DataFrame with only columns names for testing
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=a)
df.columns = [' '.join(y for y in x if 'Unnamed' not in y) for x in df.columns]
#print (df)

df = df.filter(regex='Applicance Name|Firmware')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Applicance Name,
          Appliance Details Composer Firmware Verion, 
          BTfra Details Synergy 20Gb BTterconnect LBTk Module Firmware Version,
          BTfra Details Synergy 12Gb SAS Connection Module Firmware Verion, 
          BTfra Details Virtual Connect SE 40Gb F8 Module for Synergy Firmware Verion]
Index: []
```

Comment: You are champ @jezrael.